# Best way to present editable tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, handsontable

I've inherited the job of maintaining and developing an internal journaling system for registering inventory in tables on a local website. It is a website made in PHP, using jquery and handontable to list data from a MySQL database. All fields in the table are editable by the users.

Today the loading of data can be slow (10-15 seconds in the largest tables), which is mainly because of the loops used to populate the table and adjust the column sizes.

What do you think would be the best way to fix this issue? Should I reduce load times by fixing the loops, and keep handsontable as table library? Or should I scrap the old solution and implement something new?

Thanks :)

Comment: how about adding a pagination instead? meaning just load like 100 first and cut it down by pages

Comment: Ye, that could have been a solution, but because of the way we use the information on the tables, we need them to be accessable on one page. However there's not an insane amount of data. Around 700 rows at the most so it's only slow because of the loops used to populate and adjust the tables.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I just saw you're using handsontable so my answer doesn't really provide a solution, as handsontable already uses a kind of list virtualization. I'll leave my answer anyway

---

**Original Answer**

What you can probably do is some sort of list virtualization, although this might be a bit tricky with table elements because you need absolute positioning and control of heights. Also it generally assumes that all rows have the same height.

The general idea is you only want to bother with rendering what's currently on the screen. Assuming you can fit 50 rows into your viewport at any time, you're measuring and updating 650 rows that don't matter. If you have 500000 rows, like in the fiddle, you're problem is going to be exponentially out of control.

Without knowing what you're doing exactly, here's a very general approach to the problem:

```
var elements = [];
var maxLength = 500000; // Number of elements we're going to generate
var itemHeight = 20; // We need a static row height for this to work
var totalHeight = itemHeight * maxLength; // The total height of the content
var $scrollContainer = $('#scroller-container'); // The container that will scroll
var $scrollContent = $('#scroller-contents'); // The content container for our items.

// We need to set the total height of the content so that absolute positioning works and the container receives the correctly sized scroll bar.
$scrollContent.css({ height: `${totalHeight}px` });

// Generate elements.
for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    elements.push({
    name: `item_${i}`,
    value: `value_${i + 100}`
  });
}

// By taking some measurements we will find out
// here exactly what items need to be rendered.
function obtainRenderableItems () {
  // The size of our scrollable container
  var containerHeight = $scrollContainer.height();

  // How many items will fit inside the viewable area of our scrollable container
  var viewport_count = Math.ceil(containerHeight / itemHeight);

  // Where is it currently scrolled to.
  var scrollPosition = $scrollContainer.scrollTop();

  // The index of the first item in the viewable area
  var start = Math.floor(scrollPosition / itemHeight);

  // This calculation gives us a number of items to buffer on either side
  // which prevents some janky behaviour when scrolling over yet unrendered items
  var preScan = start - viewport_count <= 0 ? 0 : start - viewport_count;

  // Basically we get the elements visible on the viewports by the current start
  // index, and a buffer at the beginning and the end of the same amount of items
  // in the viewport.
  return elements.slice(preScan, preScan + (viewport_count * 3)).map((element, index) => {
    return [preScan + index, element];
  });
};

// Convert it to HTML, you can do whatever here, demo only.
function generateHTML (elements) {
    return elements.map(el => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'element';
    div.style.height = `${itemHeight}px`;
    div.style.top = `${el[0] * itemHeight}px`;

    div.innerHTML = `${el[1].name} - ${el[1].value}`;

    return div.outerHTML;
  }).join('');
}

// When we scroll we recalculate what items need to be shown and rerender them
// inside the page.
function onScroll (event) {
    let items = obtainRenderableItems();
  let htmlContent = generateHTML(items);

  $scrollContent.html(htmlContent);
}

$scrollContainer.scroll(onScroll);

// Run at the beginning
onScroll();
```

The jQuery example above is based on a React component I wrote for exactly this purpose. You'll have to excuse my jQuery I haven't used it in years.

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqogmars/3/)

There are a number of caveats with this approach. The major one being the row height must be the same for all rows, which is not workable for a number of situations. It also relies on a fixed container height, although the flex model can work around this.